# Mapster from ExpandoObject to Dto - how to prevent setting missing keys to Null in Dto?

Tags: mapster

I have an object representing an update:

```
var update = new ExpandoObject();
update.AddSafely("Name", "Mary");
```

This property is part of a dto, like:

```
public class Dto
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Other {get; set;
}

var data = new Dto { Name = "John", Other = "SomeData" };
```

Now when I map, all (other) properties not in the source dictionary are set to their default.

```
// Name = "Mary" but Other = null
update.Adapt(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [IgnoreNullValues](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Shallow-merge#copy-vs-merge)